# SinonJS 101 error

Tags: qunit, sinon

I'm try to learn this tech and somehow getting stuck at the opening.

Please tell me why this test isn't working.  What obvious thing did I miss?

```
var myfunc = function() {
    alert('hello');
}

test("should spy on myfunc", function() {
    var mySpy = sinon.spy(myfunc);
    myfunc();
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(mySpy);

});
```

Comment: That looks correct to me. What output are you getting?

Answer (score 2):

It's the scope of myfunc. This works:

```
var o = {
    myfunc: function() {
        alert('hello');
    }
};

test("should spy on myfunc", function() {
    var mySpy = sinon.spy(o, "myfunc");
    o.myfunc();
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(mySpy);
    ok(true); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason your test is not working is because you're not invoking the spy, rather the original function.

And the reason @carbontax's example works is because in that case, `o.myfunc` is replaced by the spy automatically; so when you invoke `o.myfunc`, you're actually invoking the spy.

Answer (score 1):

As Mrchief said, you are not invoking `spy` but calling `myfunc();`, you should invoke spy something like.

```
test("should spy on myfunc", function() {
    var mySpy = sinon.spy(myfunc);
    mySpy(); // <= should called instead of myfunc()
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(mySpy);
});
```